# AHK Toggle on and off

Tags: autohotkey

So I have this script :

```
~$LButton::
    KeyWait LButton, T0.0
    If ErrorLevel
        While GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
            Click
            Sleep 0
        }
```

And I want it to be on if I press F3 and to be off if I press F3 or something else like F4.Like a toggle script on and off.Disable and Enable.So for example,F3 I use the script,I want to do something else F3,I come back and want to use the script F3.And so on.
I am new to scripting so if someone could help me that would be nice,thank you.
I tried to make it myself but the most I got was press designated key  then script runs,press click then script stops,but I don't want it to stop I want it to constantly run until I press the special key,and be stopped until I press the special key again.

I tried to make a simple script but I want to be capable to turn it on and off how many times I need to.
So I want someone to help me do my script and tell me how to do the toggle on and off.And I want someone to show me what I am missing and how is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1 

; Press F3 once to enable rapid-click.
; Press F3 once again to disable it.

F3:: rapid_click := ! rapid_click ; changes the value of the variable rapid_click between 1 (true) and 0 (false)

~LButton::
    While(rapid_click && GetKeyState("LButton", "P")) 
    { ; If rapid_click is true and LButton is held down
        Click
    }
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option... just a basic toggle you can use as needed.

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 4   ; Sets the maximum number of simultaneous threads per hotkey.
#NoEnv           ; Avoids script checking empty variables.
#Persistent          ; Keeps a script running until ExitApp or user closes it.
#SingleInstance Force    ; Attempts to launch an already-running script are ignored.
SetBatchLines -1         ; Run script at maximum speed.
    
    F3:: 
        Toggle := !Toggle
            if (Toggle = 1) {
                Soundbeep, 1900, 300
                MsgBox, 48,,Toggle Is`nActive., 3
    ;;  Put Your Active Code Here.
        } else {
                Soundbeep, 1500, 300
                MsgBox, 262208,,Toggle Is`nNOT`nActive., 3
    ;;  Put Other Code Here, Or A Return If You Want Nothing Else To Happen.
        }
    Return
```